# Angular: how to define two possible values for a string variable

Tags: typescript-typings

Is it possible to define a variable with the type string and then define which possible values that string can have?

```
colorScheme?: string = 'positive|negative'; //must be a string 
                                             and must have the value "positive" or "negative"
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
It does not appear to work when defined in a component:

```
type ColorScheme = 'positive' | 'negative';

export class MyButtonComponent {
      @Input() colorScheme?: ColorScheme;
```

Now it is correct. Thank you.

Comment: `colorScheme?: 'positive' | 'negative = ...'`

Comment: why the =..."? Can you clarify me? Thank you.

Comment: that's where you put whatever value you want to assign initially

Comment: Can you write what to write? colorScheme?: 'positive' | 'negative = positive' ? Thank you.

Comment: yes, exactly: `colorScheme?: 'positive' | 'negative' = "positive"`

Comment: When using it in the template: <p colorScheme="positive"></p> it give an error.:r TS2820: Type '"positive"' is not assignable to type 'ColorScheme | undefined'. Did you mean '"positive "'? But if i try with <p colorScheme="'positive'"></p> gives a similar error:  - error TS2820: Type '"'positive'"' is not assignable to type 'ColorScheme | undefined'. Did you mean '"positive "'? What is the trick to use it? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, it was an error in the template! I was missing the {{}} around colorSchme. Now it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to keep these two options to choose, but also allowing any other string to be used?

Comment: Solution:  'positive' | 'negative' | string (just for anyone that might visit this question)

Comment: if you are writing `'positive' | 'negative' | string`, then this just collapses down to just `string`. So there is no benefit in writing both explicit strings.

Comment: I know. But still appears the two options when using the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) !

```
type ColorScheme = 'positive' | 'negative';

const scheme1: ColorScheme = 'negative'; // ok
const scheme2: ColorScheme = 'positive'; // ok 
const scheme3: ColorScheme = 'foobar'; // ko
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJwMoGMAWEC20C8UA5GHAM4CWwFAbhEVAD7EB2EA5gIbV1EDcAKAHo4LMsChksuCAEYAXLEQoM2PFEJE2XHvT5QA9AahwA1sNHjJ0vACZF8JGhsFipSrv6HjZqBbESUmoQAMwOys7BGsQAZnBwAEacyF5GUKZwQA)

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood here to place the type. Thank you.